# docker-compose: Can't connect application container with mysql container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, pymysql

I am having trouble to make the container that contains a python/bottle web app to reach the mysql server/container.

`docker-compose build`:

```
Step 8/9 : RUN python3 bin/initdb.py
 ---> Running in 30d963677711
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 583, in connect
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 707, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/initdb.py", line 18, in <module>
    password=config('MYSQL_PASSWORD', default='tspass')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 325, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 630, in connect
    raise exc
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)")
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c python3 bin/initdb.py' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql
    env_file: .env
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/app/init.sql
    networks:
      - "dock"
    expose:
      - "3306"
    # on host it's mapped on 33060

  web:
    container_name: app
    build: .
    env_file: .env
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db:db
    networks:
      - "dock"
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"

networks:
  dock:
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian:stable

EXPOSE 8888
# CMD ["./bin/run.sh"]

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential python3 python3-dev python3-pip python3-setuptools
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt

RUN python3 bin/initdb.py
RUN python3 main.py 0.0.0.0 8888
```

`initdb.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pymysql
from decouple import Config, RepositoryEnv

...

conn = pymysql.connect(
    host=config('DB_HOST', default='db'),  # NOT ACCESSIBLE?
    port=config('DB_PORT', default=3306, cast=int),
    db=config('MYSQL_DATABASE', default='db1'),
    user=config('MYSQL_USER', default='user'),
    password=config('MYSQL_PASSWORD', default='password')
)
```

`.env`:

```
# DEPLOYMENT
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306

# DOCKER MYSQL
MYSQL_HOST="0.0.0.0"
MYSQL_ROOT_HOST="%"
MYSQL_ROOT_USER=root
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=toor
MYSQL_DATABASE=db1
MYSQL_USER=user
MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
```

Any thoughts how to debug this?

PS: The above setup works perfectly without docker, by changing `DB_HOST=db` to `DB_HOST=localhost` and running `python main.py`

Comment: I think you are facing DB connection readiness issue. You need to make `web` wait for `db` to accept connections first so before `RUN python3 bin/initdb.py` you need to verify that `db` container is ready to accept connections (not talking about if the container is up or not). https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: @BentCoder You were right thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, any other container/service is not present in the `build` stage, so you can't access any other container (like 'db'). 
You may run any startup script during the container startup using the dockerfile CMD or ENTRYPOINT, for example:

myEntryPoint.sh (created in the root folder

```
python3 bin/initdb.py
python3 main.py 0.0.0.0 8888
```

Dockerfile

```
COPY myEntryPoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /myEntryPoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/myEntryPoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Thanks combining BentCoder's answer with yours solved this issue, although other issues occured.

Answer (score 0):

Modified files, based on both answers above, solving this particular issue are:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:stable

EXPOSE 8888

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential python3 python3-dev python3-pip python3-setuptools

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt
RUN chmod +x ./bin/*

CMD ["./bin/run.sh"]
```

`bin/wait-for-it.sh`:
as is

`bin/run.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

./bin/wait-for-it.sh -h db -p 3306 -- python3 ./bin/initdb.py
./bin/wait-for-it.sh -h db -p 3306 -- python3 ./main.py 0.0.0.0 8888
```